# How to save data dynamically from a View in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I want to build a Questionnaire MVC5 project. 
I have a MSSQL database with several tables like: Employee, Questions, Results ...

I made a new MVC5 project, I add it the model base on my database and I manage all CRUD operations need it.

Now I made an view for Questionar :

```
@model IEnumerable<ChestionarMVC.Models.FormQuestion>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chestionar";
}

<h2>Chestionar</h2>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
   @Html.Partial("_Chestionar",item)
    }
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

And a partialView to show each question with 2 text area, one for the answer and one for some aditional info :

```
@model ChestionarMVC.Models.FormQuestion

<table border="1" style="width:100%">

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question)
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Raspuns <br />
                <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="80" style="width:800px; height:100px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Document <br />
                <textarea id="TextArea2" rows="2" cols="80" style="width:400px"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to save in the tblResults the QuestionID, Answer and Document. 
In webforms I made a usercontrol, then I used Foreach usercontrol , and saved to database.

In MVC how can I save all?

This is the QuestionsModel:

```
namespace ChestionarMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class FormQuestion
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public FormQuestion()
        {
            this.FormResults = new HashSet<FormResult>();
            this.TBLPos = new HashSet<TBLPos>();
        }

        public int idQuestion { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public int idCategory { get; set; }
        public int idPosition { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Ordine { get; set; }

        public virtual FormCategory FormCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual Formular Formular { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<FormResult> FormResults { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TBLPos> TBLPos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is the ResultsMOdel:

```
namespace ChestionarMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class FormResult
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public FormResult()
        {
            this.Documentes = new HashSet<Documente>();
        }

        public int idResult { get; set; }
        public int idUser { get; set; }
        public int idQuestion { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string RefferenceDocument { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StampDate { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Documente> Documentes { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual FormQuestion FormQuestion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is the Questionnaire ActionResult used to generate the Questionnaire-View:

```
    public ActionResult Chestionar()
    {
        var formQuestions = db.FormQuestions;
        return View(formQuestions.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Firstly your not giving your textarea's a name attribute (so nothing will post back). Second, you cannot use a partial in a `foreach` loop to generate controls. Third, Your not creating any elements to identify the question. You need to show your models and your controller methods before you can get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a view model containing the properties you want for the view (note add other validation attributes as required to suit your needs)

```
public class QuestionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Question { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter and answer")]
  public string Answer { get; set; }
  public string Document { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an `EditorTemplate`. In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/QuestionVM.cshtml`

```
@model QuestionVM
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question)
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Question)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Question)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Answer)
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Answer)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Answer)
... // ditto for Document (as for Answer)
```

And in the main view

```
@model IEnumerable<QuestionVM>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
  <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

Note that the `EditorFor()` method will generate the html for each Question based on the template, and importantly will add the correct name attributes that enable your form controls to be posted back and bound to your model

The in the controller

```
public ActionResult Chestionar()
{
  // Get data model and map to view models
  var model = db.FormQuestions.Select(q => new QuestionVM()
  {
    ID = q.idQuestion,
    Question = q.Question,
    Answer = .....,
    Document = .... // see notes below
  };
  return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Chestionar(IEnumerable<QuestionVM> model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  // Get the data model again, map the view model properties back to the data model
  // update properties such as user and date
  // save and redirect
}
```

Side note: your question indicates an (one) Answer and Document for each question, yet you current models for the Question have a collection (`ICollection<FormResult> FormResults`) containing properties for the `Answer` and `RefferenceDocument` so its not clear if you want to add multiple answers and documents for each Question, or just one.

Comment: For each user there is a set of questions base on his Position. Each user is giving one answer for each question, and I store his input in the table FormResult. Thank you for your time, this is my first MVC project and I am trying to understand it. I am also a beginner in programming.

Comment: I suggest that you start by just creating a few dummy `QuestionVM` objects and add them to a collection (`List<QuestionVM>`) in the GET method and pass that to the view  (forget the data models for the moment) to see how it all works and also inspect the html your generating so you understand how model binding works.